# Share Domain DLL between webjob and web api?

Tags: c#, azure, domain-driven-design, microservices

I use webjob to process messages queue and web API to process REST request.
What is the solution for share domain between this two application types that have the same bounded context? 
Can I reference the same Domain DLL or it is a bad design choose?

Comment: To clarify, you have a WebJob and a Web API application running on the same Azure Web App, and you want to know the advantages/disadvantages of using a single DLL that is referenced by both?

Comment: yes, that's it, more specifically for business DLL

Comment: Please see my answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43568325/sharing-custom-code-between-two-nodejs-microservices/43583668#43583668

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sharing custom code between two NodeJS microservices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43568325/sharing-custom-code-between-two-nodejs-microservices)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend setting up your Visual Studio solution with the following projects:

1. WebAPI project
2. Application tier project
3. WebJob project
   4 - N. [All other projects, like data access tier]

The WebAPI and WebJob projects both reference the Application tier project.

Within the Web App, the WebAPI and WebJob projects each have their own copy of the Application tier DLL. There's nothing to gain by keeping one copy of the DLL on your Web App and sharing it between the two (Besides saving a few KB of disk space). But it will add complexity to your deployment.

Also, you could at some point in the future want to move your WebJob to a different Web App. Sharing a single copy of the DLL between the two will force you to make changes to do so.

Comment: yes but in microservice that is recommanded no sharing code between microservice, so webAPI and WebJob are the same microservice ? but it is not the same EXE.. so I am confused

Comment: @ArDumez what he's saying is that WebAPI and WebJob are just different presentation layers for the same microservice, I think

Comment: @ArDumez, if you create an ASP.NET Web Application Web API project called Foo, that will compile to Foo.DLL, and all of its supporting libraries. If you create an Azure WebJob project called Bar, it will compile down to Bar.exe and its referenced libraries. If Application is a class library referenced by each project, both Foo and Bar will have a separate copy of Application.DLL. This is what you want.